# TextColor of Xamarin.Forms SearchBar

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, searchbar, custom-renderer

I have a Xamarin.Forms SearchBar on a StackLayout with a dark background color.

By default the input field is dark as well, probably due to a transparent background. To modify the search bar background color there is a `BackgroundColor` property. (In the example below I set it to dark gray.)

But how to adjust the text color? There is no such property. And even with a custom search bar renderer I don't find a solution.

This is how it looks with just the placeholder:

[image]

...and with some input (black "Hello world!" on a pretty dark background):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a custom **View** that has a *bindable-property* like **ForegroundTextColor** and then create a custom renderer.

In the custom renderer you can inherit from the platform specific renderer, i.e. on **WindowsPhone** it is:-

**Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinPhone.SearchBarRenderer**

You can then monitor for property changes to the *bindable-property* you created and set the **platform native control** *Text-color* that is used to change the appearance of the non-editing view of the **SearchBar**.

You also have to monitor for **IsFocused** and apply the colouring on **WindowsPhone**, at least, also.  This may also apply for other platforms possibly as well.

**Update 1:-**

**========**

In reply to your comment you don't have to render the whole **SearchBar** yourself.

If you inherit from the **renderer** you are able to customize things finer.

With specific reference to **Android** to achieve this you have to get reference to **AutoCompleteTextView** and then you can call **SetTextColor** to change the color.

**Update 2:-**

**==========**

**SearchBar** is a composite control in **Android**.

The **AutoCompleteTextView** is buried rather deep in the hierarchy.

On **4.4** this can be found using the following code.  Other versions may well differ.  This is by no means a good approach necessarily for production using ordinal indexes however:-

```
AutoCompleteTextView objAutoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)(((this.Control.GetChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).GetChildAt(2) as ViewGroup).GetChildAt(1) as ViewGroup).GetChildAt(0);
```

Where **this** is the **renderer** class.

You can then call **objAutoTextView.SetTextColor** with the color to achieve the change in color to the **SearchBar** foreground text.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not allow me to set the color of the *editable* text. ```SearchBar``` seems not to have such a property (at least on Android). And I didn't want to render the whole search bar by myself.

Comment: I've updated my answer with updated info specific for **Android**, See (Update 1).  The approach does work without rewriting the SearchBar.

Comment: I can't find the ```AutoCompleteTextView``` within a ```SearchBar``` or ```SearchBarRenderer```. :/

Comment: On **Android** it is buried rather deep in the hierarchy.  I've updated my answer with more and code for **Android**, See (Update 2)

Comment: Great, Update 2 is what I was looking for. It's working well for my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code for an Android Custom renderer that will do the trick. I would upload a screenshot, but I don't have enough points yet :(

```
using System;

using Android.Widget;
using Android.Text;
using G = Android.Graphics;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly:ExportRenderer( typeof(MySearchBar), typeof(Some.Namespance.MySearchBar_Droid) )]

namespace Some.Namespace
{
    public class MySearchBar_Droid : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged( ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> args )
        {
            base.OnElementChanged( args );

            // Get native control (background set in shared code, but can use SetBackgroundColor here)
            SearchView searchView = (base.Control as SearchView);
            searchView.SetInputType( InputTypes.ClassText | InputTypes.TextVariationNormal );

            // Access search textview within control
            int textViewId = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier( "android:id/search_src_text", null, null );
            EditText textView = (searchView.FindViewById( textViewId ) as EditText);

            // Set custom colors
            textView.SetBackgroundColor( G.Color.Rgb( 225, 225, 225 ) );
            textView.SetTextColor( G.Color.Rgb( 32, 32, 32 ) );
            textView.SetHintTextColor( G.Color.Rgb( 128, 128, 128 ) );

            // Customize frame color
            int frameId = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier( "android:id/search_plate", null, null );
            Android.Views.View frameView = (searchView.FindViewById( frameId ) as Android.Views.View);
            frameView.SetBackgroundColor( G.Color.Rgb( 96, 96, 96 ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now you can upload I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a very simple solution:

I accidentally used the Android Theme `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` and modified all colors explicitly. But to get a bright text color on a search bar you better use `@android:style/Theme.Holo`.

It does not allow you to set the color very precisely, but changing it from black to white was all I needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following changes in the xaml if you are using xaml to obtain the different text color of search bar on different platforms:

```
<SearchBar x:Name="Search"
           Placeholder="Search"    
           TextChanged="SearchBar_OnTextChanged"  
           SearchButtonPressed="OnSearch" BackgroundColor="#19588F">
         <SearchBar.TextColor>
             <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                    <OnPlatform.iOS>
                      Black
                    </OnPlatform.iOS>
                    <OnPlatform.Android>
                      White
                    </OnPlatform.Android>
                    <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                      White
                    </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
             </OnPlatform>
         </SearchBar.TextColor>
 </SearchBar>
```

Comment: This helped me to change the font color.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, another way:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof (CustomSearchBar), typeof (CustomSearchBarRenderer))]

namespace Bahai.Android.Renderers 
{
public class CustomSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            SearchBar element = (SearchBar) this.Element;
            var native = (global::Android.Widget.SearchView) Control;

            // do whatever you want to the controls here!
            //--------------------------------------------
            // element.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
            // native.SetBackgroundColor(element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            // native.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White.ToAndroid());

            //The text color of the SearchBar / SearchView 
            AutoCompleteTextView textField = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                (((Control.GetChildAt(0) as ViewGroup)
                    .GetChildAt(2) as ViewGroup)
                    .GetChildAt(1) as ViewGroup)
                    .GetChildAt(0);

            if (textField != null)
                textField.SetTextColor(Color.White.ToAndroid());
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SearchBar has a TextColor property. At least in Xamarin 5.

```
<SearchBar
        TextColor="Black"
        Text="{Binding SearchString}">
```